# Big unused space on the right of wordpress page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

How do I remove this big unused space on the right side of my wordpress page?
Here is my website[clicke here](http://www.vumiche.com) and here is my css i am using for this layout. I have not been able to figure it out I have tried a few codes with .content and #main and page and still none of them worked. what do I do to manually remove the big right area because the page is too wide. I cant find width change anywhere.

```
/*
Theme Name:Urania
Theme URL: http://www.fabthemes.com/urania/
Description: Free WordPress theme released by fabthemes.com
Author: Fabthemes.com
Author URI: www.fabthemes.com
Version: 1.0.0
Tags:  Blue, Violet, white, two-columns, jQuery slider, featured thumbnail, right-sidebar, twitter, fixed-width, theme-options,threaded-comments, banner ads, adsense, wordpress 3.

*/

* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    background:#000000 url(images/body.jpg) top center no-repeat;
    font-family:Arial,Tahoma,Century gothic, sans-serif;
    color:#161514;
    font-size:13px;
    }
img {
    border:0;
    margin: 0 0;
    }
a {
    color:#0B98D9;
    text-decoration:none;
    outline:none;
    }
a:hover {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none
        }
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {

    }
blockquote {
    padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    color:#59666f;
    font-style: normal;

    }
.clear {
    clear:both;
    }

table{
    margin: 10px 0 10px;
    }

table td, table th{
    text-align: left;
    padding: .4em .8em;
    }

table th{
    background: #ccc ;
    color: #444;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: normal;
    }

table td{
    background: #e4e4e4;
    }

table tr.even td{
    background: #eee;
    }

table tr:hover td{
    background: #FFF9DF;
    }
img.centered  {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    }

img.alignnone {
    padding: 5px 5px;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    display: inline;
    background:#CECECE;

    }

img.alignright {
    padding: 5px 5px;
    margin: 5px 0px 10px 10px;
    display: inline;
    background:#CECECE;

    }

img.alignleft {
    padding: 5px 5px;
    margin: 5px 10px 10px 0px;
    display: inline;
    background:#CECECE;

    }

.aligncenter {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

.alignright {
    float: right;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    }

.alignleft {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    }

.wp-caption {

    text-align: center;
    background:#CECECE;
    padding: 4px 0px 5px 0px;
    margin: 5px 5px ;
    }

.wp-caption img {
    margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;

    }

.wp-caption p.wp-caption-text {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 12px;
    }
.rounded{

    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.inshadow{
    box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 10px #B9B9B9;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 10px #B9B9B9;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 10px #B9B9B9;
}

.dropshadow{
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #1F1611;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #1F1611;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #1F1611;
}   

/* The Outer cover */

#wrapper{
    width: 900px;
    text-align:left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 10px;
} 

#casing {
    padding:0px 0px 10px 0px;
    float:left;
    width:900px;
    margin:10px 0px 0px 0px;
    background:url(images/casing.png) repeat-y;
    }       

/* The Header */
#top {
    height:110px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    width:900px;
    position:relative;

    }


.blogname {
    width:400px;
    margin:25px 0 0 10px;
    height:70px;
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
    padding-left:0px;

    }

.blogname h1  {
    font-size:34px;
    padding:0 0 0px 0;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-family:Georgia,Arial,Tahoma,Century gothic, sans-serif;    
    }

.blogname h1  a:link, .blogname h1  a:visited{ 
    color: #fff; 
    display:block;
    margin:5px 0 0 0px;
    }

.blogname h1  a:hover { 
    color: #fff; 
    }

.blogname h2 {
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:normal;
    color: #EA6FFF; 
    }


/* The Search */



/* The Search */


#search {
    display:inline-block;
    width:271px;
    padding:0px 0px ;
    height:32px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    right:30px;
    background:url(images/search.png) no-repeat;
}
#search form {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0;
}

#search fieldset {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}

#search p {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 85%;
}

#s {
    width:220px;
    margin:7px 0px 0px 20px;
    padding: 4px 5px;
    height:14px;
    font: normal 100% "Tahoma", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#333;
    background:#CFCFCF;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    float:left;

    display:inline;
}
input#searchsubmit{
    float:right;
    display:inline;
    margin:0px 10px 0px 0px;
    background:#610501;
    color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #790601;
}

#searchpage{
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    margin:10px 10px 0px 10px;
}

#sform{
    width:500px;
    border:none;
    padding:4px 5px;
}

#formsubmit{
    float:right;
    background:url(images/sfrm.png) repeat-x;
    border-left:1px solid #ccc!important;
    border:none;
    padding:3px 5px;
}
.sbox{
    padding:10px 15px;
}
.shead{
    margin-bottom:30px;

}
.shead p{
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    color:#222;
}

h2.stitle{
text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight:normal;

}

.searchmeta{
    margin-top:5px; 
    color:#43873e;
}


/*Page menu*/
#foxmenucontainer{
    height:41px;
    display:block;
    padding:0px 0 0px 0px;
    font-size: 12px ;
    font-weight:normal;
    background:url(images/menu.png) repeat-x;
    }
#menu{
    margin:0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    height:40px;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:900px;

    }

#menu ul {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }

#menu li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color:#a279c5;
    line-height:40px;   
    }

#menu li a, #menu li a:link, #menu li a:visited {
    color:#a279c5;
    line-height:40px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 10px ;

    }

#menu li a:hover, #menu li a:active {
    background:#2e113a;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 10px ;
    line-height:40px;
    text-decoration: none;

    }

#menu li li a, #menu li li a:link, #menu li li a:visited {
    background: #2E113A;
    width: 150px;
    color:#a279c5;
    font-weight: normal;
    float: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 10px ;
    line-height:32px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #3B164B;

    }

#menu li li a:hover, #menu li li a:active {
    background: #17061F;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0px 10px ;
    line-height:32px;
    }

#menu li ul {
    z-index: 9999;
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
    height: auto;
    width: 170px;
    margin: 0px;
    background:#2E113A;
    }

#menu li li { 
    }

#menu li ul a { 
    width: 140px;
    }

#menu li ul a:hover, #menu li ul a:active { 
    }

#menu li ul ul {
    margin: -33px 0 0 170px;
    }

#menu li:hover ul ul, #menu li:hover ul ul ul, 
#menu li.sfhover ul ul, #menu li.sfhover ul ul ul {
    left: -999em;
    }

#menu li:hover ul, #menu li li:hover ul, 
#menu li li li:hover ul, #menu li.sfhover ul, 
#menu li li.sfhover ul, #menu li li li.sfhover ul {
    left: auto;
    }

#menu li:hover, #menu li.sfhover { 
    position: static;
    }


/*  menu*/

#catmenubox{
    height:40px;
    width:880px;
    padding:10px;
    background:#fff;
}
#catmenucontainer{
    height:40px;
    display:block;
    padding:0px 0 0px 0px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight:normal;
    background:#0b98d9;
    }

#catmenu{
    margin:0px auto;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    height:40px;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:880px;
        }

#catmenu ul {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }

#catmenu li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color:#043b54;
    line-height:40px;
    }

#catmenu li a, #catmenu li a:link, #catmenu li a:visited {
    color:#043b54;
    line-height:40px;   
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 10px ;

    }

#catmenu li a:hover, #catmenu li a:active {
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 10px ;
    line-height:40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background:#0982ba;
    }

#catmenu li li a, #catmenu li li a:link, #catmenu li li a:visited {
    background:#0982ba;
    width: 150px;
    color: #0D081C;
    font-weight: normal;
    float: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 10px ;
    line-height:35px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0B98D9;
    }

#catmenu li li a:hover, #catmenu li li a:active {
    background:#00638F;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0px 10px ;
    line-height:35px;
    }

#catmenu li ul {
    z-index: 9999;
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
    height: auto;
    width: 170px;
    margin: 0px;
    background:#00150E;
    }

#catmenu li li { 
    }

#catmenu li ul a { 
    width: 140px;
    }

#catmenu li ul a:hover, #catmenu li ul a:active { 
    }

#catmenu li ul ul {
    margin: -36px 0 0 170px;
    }

#catmenu li:hover ul ul, #catmenu li:hover ul ul ul, 
#catmenu li.sfhover ul ul, #catmenu li.sfhover ul ul ul {
    left: -999em;
    }

#catmenu li:hover ul, #catmenu li li:hover ul, 
#catmenu li li li:hover ul, #catmenu li.sfhover ul, 
#catmenu li li.sfhover ul, #catmenu li li li.sfhover ul {
    left: auto;
    }

#catmenu li:hover, #catmenu li.sfhover { 
    position: static;
    }

/* Main Content*/   


#content {
    float:left;
    width:620px;
    height:100%;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin:10px 0px 0px 0px;
    display:inline;
    overflow:hidden;


    }   

.post {
    margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
    height:100%;
    color:#555;
    position:relative;
    padding:0px 0px;
    }
.postimg{
    margin:5px 0px 5px 10px;
    padding:5px;
    width:570px;
    height:200px;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ddd;

}

.title{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px 10px;

}   

.title  h2 {
    margin: 0px 0 0px 0;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 10px;
    font-size: 26px ;
    font-weight:normal;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-family:georgia;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #bbb;
        }

.title  h2 a, .title  h2 a:link, .title  h2 a:visited  {
    color:#3B164B;
    background-color: transparent;
    }

.title  h2 a:hover  {
    color: #4c5262;
    background-color: transparent;
    }   


.titlemeta{
    padding:5px 0px 0px 10px;
}

.author{
    color:#35241A;
    padding:2px 5px 2px 20px;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #fff;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:10px;
    margin-left:0px;
    background:url(images/user.png) no-repeat;
    }

.clock{
    color:#35241A;
    padding:2px 5px 2px 20px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
        text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #fff;
    font-size:10px;
    background:url(images/clock.png) no-repeat;
}   

.comm{
    color:#fff;
    padding:8px 10px 0px 10px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:10px;
    float:left;

}

.comm a:link,
.comm a:visited {
    color:#fff;

}
.comm a:hover{
    color:#fff;
}


.postmeta {
    padding:0px 0px 0px 10px;
    height:30px;
    background:Url(images/postmeta.png) repeat-x;
            }

a.rmore{
    color:#fff;
    padding:8px 20px 0px 10px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:10px;
    float:right;

}


.categ{
    padding:5px 0 5px 5px;
    color:#000;
    font-size:10px;
}

.categ a:link,.categ a:visited{
    color:#B21F48;

    }

.categ a:hover{
    color:#000;
    }

.cover{
    padding:5px 10px;
}
.entry {
    margin:0 0;
    padding: 0px 10px  ;

    }   

.entry a:link,
.entry a:visited {
    color:#0069BF;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.entry a:hover {
    color:#00499F;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.entry ul, .entry ol{
  margin: .4em 0 1em;
  line-height: 150%;
}


.entry ul li, .entry ol li{
  list-style-position:outside;
  margin-left: 1.6em;
}

.entry p{
    margin:5px 0px;
    padding:5px 0px;
    line-height:24px;
    font-size:13px;
}


#entry-author-info{
    padding:20px 0px;
    background:url(images/authmet.png);
    margin-top:5px;
    border-top:1px solid #fcfcfc;
}

#author-avatar{
    float:left;
    padding:5px;
    background:#fff;
    margin-left:20px;
}
#author-avatar{
    float:left;
}

#author-description{
    float:left;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 10px;
    width:300px;
}
#author-description h3{
    line-height:20px;
    color:#333;

}
#author-description p{
    line-height:20px;
    color:#555;
}

#author-share{
    float:right;
    background:#fff;
    padding:3px 5px;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
}
#author-share ul{
    list-style:none;

}
#author-share ul li{
    list-style:none;
    float:right;
    margin-right:5px;

}

#catbox{
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;

}

#catbox ul{
    list-style:none;
}
#catbox ul li{
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    margin:5px 5px 0px 0px;
    padding:3px 5px;
    background:#fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
}
/* right column */
.right{

    float:right;
    width:260px;
    padding:10px 10px 0px 10px;
    display:inline;
    overflow:hidden;
}


.feedlist{
    height:33px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.feedlist ul {
    list-style:none;
}

.feedlist ul li{
    float:left;
    margin:0px 6px 0px 0px;

}
.feedlist ul li:last-child{
    float:right!important;
    margin:0px !important;
}

.blokbox,.twitbox{
    float:left;
    width:260px;
    background:#fff;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    }
.blok{
    padding:5px 0px 0px 0px;
    float:left;

}
.fentry img{
    max-width:100px;

    padding-left:6px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    float:left;

}


h3.sidetitl{
    background:#697185;
    padding:10px 10px;
    font-family:Arial, Georgia,Tahoma,Century gothic, sans-serif;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:16px;

}
/* The Sidebar */


.sidebar{
    float:left;
}

.sidebox{
    width:260px;
    margin:0px 0px 10px 0px;
    background:#f9f9f9;
    list-style:none;
    }

.sidebox ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:  0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px ;

    }
.sidebox li{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 ;
    padding: 0;

    }
.sidebox ul ul  {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
        }

.sidebox ul ul ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border:0;
    }

.sidebox ul ul ul ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border:0;

    }

.sidebox ul li {
    height:100%;
    line-height:20px;
    clear:left; 
    width: 260px;
    margin:0px 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    }


.sidebox ul li a:link, .sidebox ul li a:visited {
    display:block;
    color:#4D5362;
    border-bottom:1px solid #E0E4EF;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 10px;
    }

.sidebox ul li a:hover {
    background:#3B414F;
    color: #fff;
    }

.sidebox p {
    padding: 7px 10px;
    margin:0;
    }

.sidebox table{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    color:#787d7f;
    }   

li.recentcomments{
    padding:5px 5px;
    }


.squarebanner {
    margin:0px 0px 10px 0px;
    }

.squarebanner ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    width:260px;
    overflow:hidden;
        }

.squarebanner ul li{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;    
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    background:#402B1E;
    }
.squarebanner ul li.rbanner{
    float:right;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}

/*calendar*/

#wp-calendar{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 5px;

}
/***** Calendar Widget *****/
#wp-calendar{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 5px;

}
#calendar_wrap{

    margin:0px auto;
}

#wp-calendar caption{
    padding: 10px 5px 5px 5px ;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#375752;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:Arial,Georgia,Century gothic,  sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}


#wp-calendar th, #wp-calendar td{
    padding: 5px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    background:#333;
}

#wp-calendar td a{

    padding: 0px;
    border:none;
    color:#843400;
}
#wp-calendar td{
    background:transparent;
    border:none;
    color:#444;
}
#wp-calendar td, table#wp-calendar th{
    padding: 2px 0;
}       

/* --- FOOTER --- */

#footer {

    padding:5px 0 10px 0px;
    color:#697185;
    font-size:12px;
    margin:0px auto;

    }

#footer a:link , #footer a:visited{
        color:#697185;
    }

#footer a:hover {
        color:#697185;
    }

.fcred{

    text-align:center;
    margin:10px 0px 10px 0px;
    line-height:20px;
}


/* The Navigation */

#navigation{    
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding:5px 7px;
    width:600px;
    height:27px;
    }


/* The Attachment */

.contentCenter {
    text-align:center;
    }

/* The Page Title */

h2.pagetitle {
    padding:10px 0px;
    font-size:16px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#962F49;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    }
 h2.pagetitle a {
    color:#507409;
 }

/* Comments */

#commentsbox {

    margin:0 0px 0px 0px;

}

h3#comments{
    font-size:14px;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:10px 10px ;
    font-family:Arial,Georgia,Century gothic,  sans-serif;
        background:url(images/postmeta.png);
    border-top:1px solid #1b70a8;
    border-bottom:1px solid #1b70a8;
}


ol.commentlist {
    margin:0px 0 0;
    clear:both;
    overflow:hidden;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0px 10px;
    background:url(images/commentli.png);

}
ol.commentlist li {
    margin:10px 0px;
    line-height:18px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #CFCFCF;
    background:#F2F2F2;
}

ol.commentlist li .comment-author {
    color:#000;

}

ol.commentlist li .comment-author a:link,ol.commentlist li .comment-author a:visited{

    color:#000;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none !important;
}

ol.commentlist li .comment-author .fn {
    color:#000;
    font-weight:bold;
}

cite.fn{
    color:#000;
    font-style:normal;
}

ol.commentlist li .comment-author .avatar{
    float:right;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    background:#fff;
    padding:3px;
}

ol.commentlist li .comment-meta{
    font-size:10px;

}

ol.commentlist li .comment-meta .commentmetadata{

    color:#000;
}

ol.commentlist li .comment-meta a {
    color:#1561C2;
    text-decoration:none !important;
}

ol.commentlist li p {
    line-height:22px;
    margin-top:5px;
    color:#555;
    font-size:12px;
}

ol.commentlist li .reply{
    margin-top:10px;
    font-size:10px;

}

ol.commentlist li .reply a{
    background:#595B5F;
    border:1px solid #222;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    padding:3px 10px;
}

ol.commentlist li.odd {

}

ol.commentlist li.even {

}

ol.commentlist li ul.children {
    list-style:none;
    margin:1em 0 0;
    text-indent:0;

}

ol.commentlist li ul.children li.depth-2 {
    margin:0 0 0px 50px;

}

ol.commentlist li ul.children li.depth-3 {
    margin:0 0 0px 50px;

}

ol.commentlist li ul.children li.depth-4 {
    margin:0 0 0px 50px;

}
ol.commentlist li ul.children li.depth-5 {
    margin:0 0 0px 50px;

}
.comment-nav{
    font-size:14px;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:10px 10px ;
    font-family:Arial,Georgia,Century gothic,  sans-serif;
    background:url(images/postmeta.png);
    border-top:1px solid #1b70a8;
    border-bottom:1px solid #1b70a8;
    height:15px;
}

.comment-nav a:link,.comment-nav a:visited{
    color:#fff;
}

#respond{

    padding:0px 20px ;
    margin:10px 0px;

}

 #respond h3 {
    font-size:14px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#FFAB06;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:10px 10px ;
}

#commentform {
    padding:10px 0px;
}

#commentform p{
    margin:5px 0px ;
    color:#444;
}

#commentform p a{
    color:#0C83D4;
}

 #respond label{
    display:block;
    padding:5px 0;
    color:#444;
    }

 #respond  label small {
    font-size:10px;
}

 #respond input {
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding:5px 5px;
    margin:0 10px 10px 0;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    color:#555;
}

#commentform  input{
    width:50%;

}

#respond  input#commentSubmit {
    background:#697185;
    border:1px solid #333;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    padding:3px 10px;
    width:100px;
    margin:10px 0px;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #032434;
}

textarea#comment{
    border:none;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    width:70%;
    margin:10px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding:5px 5px;
    color:#555;
}



.widebanner{

    height:60px;
    margin-top:10px;
    padding:10px 0px;
    background:url(images/ad1.jpg) repeat-x;
    text-align:center;
}


.wp-pagenavi{

    font-size:12px;
    text-align: center !important;


}
.wp-pagenavi a, .wp-pagenavi a:link, .wp-pagenavi a:visited {

    text-decoration: none;
    background:#1561C2!important;
    border: 1px solid #094E9F !important;
    color:#fff !important;
    padding:3px 7px !important;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4px;

}


.wp-pagenavi a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.wp-pagenavi span.pages {

display:none;
}

.wp-pagenavi span.current {
    text-decoration: none;
    background:#4D5362 !important;
    border: 1px solid #40444F!important;
    color:#fff !important;
    padding:3px 7px !important;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4px;

}

.wp-pagenavi span.extend {

    text-decoration: none;
    background:#4D5362 !important;
    border: 1px solid #40444F !important;
    color:#fff !important;
    padding:3px 7px !important;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4px;

}   

.headbanner{
    float:right;
    margin:15px 15px 0px 0px;
}

.fblock{

    border-bottom:1px solid #E0E4EF;
    padding:5px 0px!important;
}

.fblock h3{
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:normal;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.fblock h3 a:link,.fblock h3 a:visited{

    font-weight:bold;
    color:#228DD3;
}

.fblock p{
    color:#4D5362;
    margin:0px !important;
    padding:3px 0px !important;
}

body { zoom: 1.3; -moz-transform: scale(1.3); -moz-transform-origin: 0 0}



@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
#container {
padding: 0;
}
#wrapper {
padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities

1. Distribute the space evenly on both the sides
2. Update the width of the site to occupy complete width of the browser

**Distribute the space evenly on both the sides**

File : style.css, Line : 170

```
#wrapper {
    width: 900px;
    text-align:left;
    margin-top: 10px auto 0 auto;
}
```

**Update the width of the site to occupy complete width of the browser**

Add these styles in style.css at the end of the file

```
#wrapper, #top, #catmenubox, #tabzine, #casing, #bottomcover, #footer {
    width : auto;
    min-width : 900px;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to get ride of it completely if I make it go away. How do I edit the width of the page and get ride of that area to the right.

Comment: For that you can try using the second method what I added.